# Understand output of vmstat memory utilization

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, solaris, solaris-10

I have a solaris box and im trying to know whether its running out of memory or if its stable.

below is the output of vmstat.

```
 kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr vc vc vc vc   in   sy   cs us sy id
 1 0 0 11426696 4603520 613 1477 449 6 6 0 0 78 22 28 29 8970 37714 22961 43 6 51
 4 0 0 4975280    0 1747 3487 805 0 0 0  0 233 41 33 44 9558 53713 15845 74 8 18
 4 0 0 4936944    0 933 1837 0  0  0  0  0 56 28 12 39 9317 46898 14648 82 7 11
 5 0 0 4943080    0 1056 2806 805 0 0 0  0 103 21 18 18 9286 46900 14866 78 8 14
 5 0 0 4942264    0 1088 2173 804 6 6 0  0 109 8 40 31 9927 56484 16495 84 8 8
 3 0 0 4942520    0 308 1018 1756 3 3 0  0 166 87 29 44 10638 64146 21413 83 9 8
 0 0 0 4942512    0 156 326 1740 0 0  0  0 370 12 33 52 11554 40375 21897 75 9 16
 2 0 0 4947384    0 294 560 845 0  0  0  0 121 18 23 20 9445 52382 17016 77 6 17
```

I can see the free column shows 0 however the sr column also shows 0

And output from top command doesn't show how much free memory available. Swap shows 0.0%

```
load averages:  11.4,  9.12,  9.24;                   
9021 processes: 9018 sleeping, 1 running, 2 on cpu
CPU states:  0.0% idle, 71.4% user, 28.6% kernel,  0.0% iowait,  0.0% swap
Memory: 24G phys mem, 16G total swap, 13G free swap
```

Am i running out of RAM?
Please suggest how to interpret this data. Do i need to increase my physical memory?

Appreciate some insights.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Solaris 11.4 `vmstat` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E72487/vmstat-8.html), there's one important thing to note:

> Without options, `vmstat` displays a one-line summary of the virtual memory activity since the system was booted.

That also applies to the first line of output from Solaris `vmstat`: it's a summary of all activity since the system was booted.

A good description of the output fields is found in the **EXAMPLES** section of the Solaris `man vmstat` page:

> **Examples**
>
> Example 1 Using vmstat
>
> The following command displays a summary of what the system is doing
> every five seconds.
>
> example% vmstat 5
>
> ```
> kthr   memory          page             disk      faults        cpu
> r b w swap  free re mf pi p fr de sr s0 s1 s2 s3  in  sy  cs us sy id
> 0 0 0 11456 4120 1  41 19 1  3  0  2  0  4  0  0  48 112 130  4 14 82
> 0 0 1 10132 4280 0   4 44 0  0  0  0  0 23  0  0 211 230 144  3 35 62
> 0 0 1 10132 4616 0   0 20 0  0  0  0  0 19  0  0 150 172 146  3 33 64
> 0 0 1 10132 5292 0   0  9 0  0  0  0  0 21  0  0 165 105 130  1 21 78
> 1 1 1 10132 5496 0   0  5 0  0  0  0  0 23  0  0 183  92 134  1 20 79
> 1 0 1 10132 5564 0   0 25 0  0  0  0  0 18  0  0 131 231 116  4 34 62
> 1 0 1 10124 5412 0   0 37 0  0  0  0  0 22  0  0 166 179 118  1 33 67
> 1 0 1 10124 5236 0   0 24 0  0  0  0  0 14  0  0 109 243 113  4 56 39
> ```
>
> example%
>
> The fields of vmstat's display are
>
> `kthr`
>
> Report the number of kernel threads in each of the three following
> states:
>
> ```
> r
>
>     the number of kernel threads in run queue
> b
>
>     the number of blocked kernel threads that are waiting for
>     resources I/O, paging, and so forth
> w
>
>     the number of swapped out lightweight processes (LWPs) that
>     are waiting for processing resources to finish.
> ```
>
> `memory`
>
> Report on usage of virtual and real memory.
>
> ```
> swap
>
>     available swap space (Kbytes)
> free
>
>     size of the free list (Kbytes)
> ```
>
> `page`
>
> Report information about page faults and paging activity. The
> information on each of the following activities is given in units per
> second.
>
> ```
> re
>
>     page reclaims — but see the –S option for how this field is modified.
> mf
>
>     minor faults — but see the –S option for how this field is modified.
> pi
>
>     kilobytes paged in
> po
>
>     kilobytes paged out
> fr
>
>     kilobytes freed
> de
>
>     anticipated short-term memory shortfall (Kbytes)
> sr
>
>     pages scanned by clock algorithm
> ```
>
> When executed in a zone and if the pools facility is active, all of
> the above (except for ‘de’) only report activity on the processors in
> the processor set of the zone's pool.
>
> `disk`
>
> Report the number of disk operations per second. There are slots for
> up to four disks, labeled with a single letter and number. The letter
> indicates the type of disk (s = SCSI, i = IPI, and so forth); the
> number is the logical unit number.
>
> `faults`
>
> Report the trap/interrupt rates (per second).
>
> ```
> in
>
>     interrupts
> sy
>
>     system calls
> cs
>
>     CPU context switches
> ```
>
> When executed in a zone and if the pools facility is active, all of
> the above only report activity on the processors in the processor set
> of the zone's pool.
>
> `cpu`
>
> Give a breakdown of percentage usage of CPU time. On MP systems, this
> is an average across all processors.
>
> ```
> us
>
>     user time
> sy
>
>     system time
> id
>
>     idle time
> ```
>
> When executed in a zone and if the pools facility is active, all of
> the above only report activity on the processors in the processor set
> of the zone's pool.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you https://www.howtogeek.com/424334/how-to-use-the-vmstat-command-on-linux/. There is explanation of those shorts.

Memory

```
swpd: the amount of virtual memory used. In other words, how much memory has been swapped out.,
free: the amount of idle (currently unused) memory.
buff: the amount of memory used as buffers.
cache: the amount of memory used as cache.
```

Swap

```
si: Amount of virtual memory swapped in from swap space.
so: Amount of virtual memory swapped out to swap space.
```

IO

```
bi: Blocks received from a block device. The number of data blocks used to swap virtual memory back into RAM.
bo: Blocks sent to a block device. The number of data blocks used to swap virtual memory out of RAM and into swap space.
```

System

```
in: The number of interrupts per second, including the clock.
cs: The number of context switches per second. A context switch is when the kernel swaps from system mode processing into user mode processing.
```

Answer (score 0):

"0" is not a valid free memory value.

By design, Solaris always makes sure a minimal amount of free memory is available. The fact the `sr` column is also equals to zero suggests there is no memory shortage. In any case, you wouldn't have been able to run `vmstat` or `top` in the first place with such an extreme RAM shortage.

You should investigate further to understand why the free memory is reported a zero. `mdb`'s `::memstat` command would be a good start:

```
# echo "::memstat" | mdb -k
```